# Unable to move jira support ticket to Done status using Rest Client

Tags: jira, jira-rest-java-api

I am using Java rest client with following maven dependency:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-app</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

And the following code:

```java
    void markDuplicateAndClose(IssueRestClient client, ...) {
        ...
        Iterable<Transition> transitions = client.getTransitions(duplicateIssue.getTransitionsUri()).claim();
        Transition doneTransition = getTransitionByName(transitions, "Done");
        String requiredFieldId = null;
        for (Field f : doneTransition.getFields()) {
            if (f.isRequired())
                requiredFieldId = f.getId();
        };
        Collection<FieldInput> fieldInputs = Arrays.asList(new FieldInput(requiredFieldId, "Duplicate"));
        TransitionInput ti = new TransitionInput(doneTransition.getId(), fieldInputs);
        promise = client.transition(keyToIssuesMap.get(duplicate), ti).claim();
        ...
    }

    
    private Transition getTransitionByName(Iterable<Transition> transitions, String stateName) {
        for (Transition t: transitions) {
            if (t.getName().equals(stateName))
                return t;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.of(400), errorCollections=[ErrorCollection{status=400, errors={customfield_10212=Could not find valid 'id' or 'value' in the Parent Option object.}, errorMessages=[]}]}
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.DelegatingPromise.claim(DelegatingPromise.java:45)
    at com.xyz.jira_accessor.jira.Util.markDuplicates(Util.java:109)
    at com.xyz.jira_accessor.jira.Util.main(Util.java:132)
Caused by: RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.of(400), errorCollections=[ErrorCollection{status=400, errors={customfield_10212=Could not find valid 'id' or 'value' in the Parent Option object.}, errorMessages=[]}]}
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient$2.apply(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:176)
```

What is wrong with my code?

As discussed in below comments, I tried to see the underlying codes for the option:

**Option shown as compulsory on the UI**
[image]

**HTML from Chrome Debugger for the same:**
[image]

And so I changed the above code to:

```java
    Collection<FieldInput> fieldInputs = Arrays.asList(new FieldInput("customfield_11607", "12091"));
    TransitionInput ti = new TransitionInput(doneTransition.getId(), fieldInputs);
    promise = client.transition(keyToIssuesMap.get(duplicate), ti).claim();
```

But it still did not work.
Just that the error message changed to:

```
errors={customfield_11607=Could not find valid 'id' or 'value' in the Parent Option object.}
```

(To Jira Team) Can you make the error messages bit more meaningful and simplify the API please? It is very hard to figure out things. Or at least, provide some more examples which are easily searchable on the Internet.

Comment: What is `customfield_10212` in your configuration?

Comment: I don't know. This is just the ID I got from the above code `requiredFieldId`. I selected this because looking at the jira UI, only one field is marked as compulsory.

Comment: Are you sure that there's only one required field for the transition, and that "Duplicate" is a valid value for it?

Comment: I am sure there is only 1 required field as I debugged all the other fields and they were required=false. Hence I am assuming that this field is the field shown as compulsory on the jira UI and "Duplicate" is one of the values shown in the dropdown for that field.

Also, from the error message `customfield_10212=Could not find valid 'id' or 'value' in the Parent Option object`, it seems that it is not able to field the customfield_10212 and the error message seems to make little sense

Comment: Custom fields have a numeric value associated with the displayed text. I think you'll need to figure out which value is associated with the string "Duplicate" and use that. You can do that by inspecting the HTML, but if you want to check that the field is the one you expect, go to `/secure/admin/ConfigureCustomField!default.jspa?customFieldId=10212` (I'm assuming Jira server or DC)

Comment: PS, the error message is very clear: It means that the field allows selection from a list of options, and that the value you have set it to is not one of them.

Comment: In the description above, I have added some screenshots that try the above suggestion but still failed to work.

Comment: I'll retract my assertion that the error message is clear. I'm not sure why you now have a different custom field name?

Comment: I am guessing the custom fields are added by company's jira admins. Not really sure though.